# static member variable in Inherited class

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee

I have a Class_A and Class_B which inherits from Class_A:

```
public class Class_A {

    public static int check_static = 10;

    Class_A() {
        check_static = 3;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(check_static);
    }
}

public class Class_B extends Class_A {

    Class_B() {         
        check_static = check_static+1;  
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(check_static); // case 1
        Class_B class_b = new Class_B();
        System.out.println(check_static); // case 2
    }
}
```

Why is that constructor of Class_B accesses different value of `check_static` and main method of Class_B accesses different value?

The second case would be because I don't instantiate Class_A in Class_B and so it picks member value (10) from Class_A but I am not sure how case 2 works.

Why does constructor of Class_B pick its value from constructor of Class_A?

Comment: Because the compiler adds `super()` if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler is about to get its job done, it will introduce a call to the superclass constructor on you behalf if no one has been added.

The rule is that the first instruction in whatever class constructor must be a call to the no-arg constructor of the same class, i.e. using `this()` or a call to the superclass constructor using `super()` keyword.

So when compiled, your `Class_B` (note that I'm not too comfortable with your class name since they don't adhere the Java naming conventions), your class constructor will look like this:

```java
Class_B(){
  super();
  check_static = check_static + 1;    
}
```

That will cause the super class constructor to be called, that is to be `Class_A()` and the flow will be as below:

1. Call to `Class_B()` will result to a call to `Class_A()`
2. Once `Class_A()` is called, the class member variable, `check_static`, will have its value assigned to **3**
3. Now back to the `Class_B()` constructor, the `check_static` will be incremented by **1**.
4. Printing the value to the console will result in a sum of **4**.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(check_static); //case 1 --- it calls the variable from class A

Class_B class_b=new Class_B(); -- as you are calling the constructor, the value changes

System.out.println(check_static);//case 2 -- prints the updated value
```

Comment: Ya I understand that , but Why does constructor of Class_B pick its value from constructor of Class_A

Comment: whenever you call the constructor of a subclass, it always invokes its parent constructor.; 

if you have a look at the output it would be more eveident

Answer (score 0):

Because when you call

```
Class_B class_b=new Class_B();
```

it would firstly new Class_B's superclass Class_A so the Class_A's constructor will be executed before the Class_B instantiate.